# Pandas string extract from a dataframe with strings resembling dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to use the Pandas string extract feature.

I have a dataframe like this:

```
lista=[ "{'FIRST_id': 'awe', 'THIS_id': 'awec_20230222_1626_i0ov0w', 'NOTTHIS_id': 'awep_20230222_1628_p8f5hd52u3oknc24'}","{'FIRST_id': 'awe', 'THIS_id': 'awec_20230222_1626_i0ov0w', 'NOTTHIS_id': 'awep_20230222_1641_jwjajtals49wc88p'}"]
dfpack=pd.DataFrame(lista,columns=["awesome_config"])
print(dfpack)
```

So in the column "awesome_config" I have some string with some information:

```
                                      awesome_config
0  {'FIRST_id': 'awe', 'THIS_id': 'awec_20230222...
1  {'FIRST_id': 'awe', 'THIS_id': 'awec_20230222...
```

I want to get only the "THIS_id" info on a column.

Therefore what I want to get is a dataframe with:

```
THIS_id
awec_20230222_1626_i0ov0w
awec_20230222_1626_i0ov0w
```

I have been trying something like:

```
#dd=dfpack['awesome_config'].str.extract(pat= "({'FIRST_id':'awe', 'THIS_id':).")
dd=dfpack['awesome_config'].str.extract(pat= "({'FIRST_id':'awe').")
print(dd)
```

But they all give me a dataframe with NaNs.

How can I use extract correctly here?

### Edit

I have come with this:

```
dd=dfpack['awesome_config'].str.extract(r"^({'FIRST_id': 'awe', 'THIS_id': )(?P<THIS_id>.*), 'NOTTHIS_id':(?P<restofit>).* ")
```

but now I got:

```
0    'awec_20230222_1626_i0ov0w'
1    'awec_20230222_1626_i0ov0w'
Name: THIS_id, dtype: object
```

so the quotations are still there, I need it without quotations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to evaluate the string into dict and then use [`str.get (str[])`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html) to get to the desired key:

```
from ast import literal_eval
key = 'THIS_id'
dd=pd.DataFrame({key:dfpack['awesome_config'].apply(literal_eval).str[key]})
print(dd)

                     THIS_id
0  awec_20230222_1626_i0ov0w
1  awec_20230222_1626_i0ov0w
```

Comment: what import do I need?

Comment: updated answer with import required.

Comment: Thanks!. In my practice code, it works, but somehow in the code I want to use it I get `ValueError: malformed node or string`....

Comment: That means the string that represents the dict doesn't represent a well-formed dict. You need to check that string where it doesn't work.

Comment: I analyzed it. Turns out it is not a string but a dictionary....Extracting from a dict is a competely different question now...

Comment: If its a dictionary you don't need to evaluate it. So just remove `apply(literal_eval)` from the above code.